# PHPhotoLibrary crashed when getting placeholderForCreatedAsset

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios10, phphotolibrary

I try to put image to custom album with this code:

```
PHAssetCollection *album = [self getMyAlbum];
UIImage *image = [self getMyImage];

[[PHPhotoLibrary sharedPhotoLibrary] performChanges:^{
    PHAssetChangeRequest *createAssetRequest = [PHAssetChangeRequest creationRequestForAssetFromImage:image];

    PHObjectPlaceholder * placeHolder = createAssetRequest.placeholderForCreatedAsset;

    PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest *albumChangeRequest = [PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest changeRequestForAssetCollection:album];

    if(placeHolder){
        [albumChangeRequest addAssets:@[ placeHolder ]];
    }

} completionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
    //doesen't matter
}];
```

So, i get many errors in users logs in this row `createAssetRequest.placeholderForCreatedAsset`

like

> 1 CoreFoundation __exceptionPreprocess + 1245624
>
> 2 libobjc.A.dylib objc_exception_throw + 34136
>
> 3 Photos __48-[PHChangeRequestHelper generateUUIDIfNecessary]_block_invoke + 116552
>
> 2 libdispatch.dylib _dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow + 79828
>
> 3 Photos -[PHChangeRequestHelper generateUUIDIfNecessary] + 115992
>
> 4 Photos -[PHAssetCreationRequest placeholderForCreatedAsset] + 244020

so `[PHChangeRequestHelper generateUUIDIfNecessary]` give me crash.

I see this only on **iOS > 10**, and I can't reproduct this in the simulator.

What is it? How to fix that?

Comment: Have you managed to find a problem?

Comment: Also this bug appears when I save the photo without inserting to the collection. Like this: 

 var placeholderAssetBlock: PHObjectPlaceholder?
        PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
            let asset = PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAsset(from: photo)
            placeholderAssetBlock = asset.placeholderForCreatedAsset
        }

Comment: what's the exception that gets thrown?

Comment: @combinatorial *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error -1.)'

Comment: @combinatorial here crash log typical http://pastebin.com/pEXQ5Bsn

Comment: have you requested authorization?

Comment: [PHPhotoLibrary requestAuthorization:^(PHAuthorizationStatus status) {

Comment: @combinatorial sure. People save photos a few times and at random attempt have a crash.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135812/discussion-between-kondratyevdev-and-combinatorial).

Comment: could you share the code for `getMyImage`?

Comment: I also face this problem in iOS 10.2.1, do you use an iphone7 to test?

Comment: @Jam no, I didn't test on 7. I can't catch this error with testing. I see it only in crash reports of other users.

Comment: @JonRose it's complicated code ;) I make a screenshot from UIView, but I think it doesn't matter how can I make or receive UIImage.

Comment: I'm getting this problem on an iPhone 6. Interestingly a co-tester is not seeing it on an iPhone 7. I have no idea how to interpret this at the moment.

Comment: Could `image` or `album` be nil?

Comment: Is this happening in ios 9 too?

Comment: Jon Rose - no Saheb Roy - no

Comment: We see this as well. I've submitted a radar @ rdar://33197332. Have you managed to work around this issue?

Comment: I face this problem too, through my Crashlytics it occurred on iOS 10 only, all versions of iOS 10

Comment: hey! any updates?

Answer (score 2):

Try Using this. Hope this is what you seek.

```
import UIKit
import Photos

protocol CameraRollViewControllerProtocol: class {
    func displayTappedImage(displayImage: UIImage)
    func scrollToCameraButtonTapped()
}

class CameraRollViewController:  UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    @IBOutlet var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    var images = [PHAsset]()
    var displayImage: UIImage!
    // used to specify the target size of the thumbnails of images in cameraRoll
    // In iPhone6 images of target size 100.0 were successfully obtained and in iPhone 6plus images of 400.0 were obtained successfully; for other target size a nil image was obtained.
    var thumbImageSize: Double!
    var targetSize: CGSize!
    weak var delegate: CameraRollViewControllerProtocol!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        collectionView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 24.0, left: 24.0, bottom: 24.0, right: 24.0)
//        if UIScreen.main.bounds.width > 375 {
//            thumbImageSize = 100.0
//        } else {
            thumbImageSize = 100.0
//        }

    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

        collectionView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [ NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.cameraRollNavigationBarTitle, NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.gothamRoundedMedium20!]

        checkPermission { (success) in
            if success {
                OperationQueue.main.addOperation({
                    self.getImages()
                })
            }
        }
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    }

    override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    }

    // MARK: - UICollectionViewDataSource
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return images.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {            
            if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "galleryPhotoCell", for: indexPath) as? CameraRollCell {

                let asset = images[indexPath.row]
                let manager = PHImageManager.default()

                if cell.tag != 0 {
                    manager.cancelImageRequest(PHImageRequestID(cell.tag))
                }

                cell.tag = Int(manager.requestImage(for: asset,
                                                    targetSize: CGSize(width: thumbImageSize, height: thumbImageSize),
                                                    contentMode: .aspectFill,
                                                    options: nil) { (result, _) in


                                                        if result != nil {
                                                            cell.imageView?.image = result
                                                        } else {
                                                            cell.imageView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "cloud-Image")
                                                        }
                })
                return cell
            }
            else {
                return UICollectionViewCell()
            }
    }

    @IBAction func CameraButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        delegate.scrollToCameraButtonTapped()
    }
}

extension CameraRollViewController {

    func getImages() {

        if images.count > 0 {
            images.removeAll()
        }

        let assets = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: PHAssetMediaType.image, options: nil) //fetchOptions)//nil)

        assets.enumerateObjects({ (object, count, stop) in
            self.images.append(object)
        })
        self.images.reverse()
        self.collectionView.reloadData()
    }

    func checkPermission( completionHandler:@escaping (_ success:Bool)->()) {

        PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization({ (status:PHAuthorizationStatus) in
            if status == .authorized {
                completionHandler(true)
            } else {
                completionHandler(false)
            }
        })
    }
}

extension CameraRollViewController {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                        layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                        sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: 96.0, height: 96.0)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout
        collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                        minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 20.0
    }
}

extension CameraRollViewController {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        // check size of Asset before loading it

        let asset = images[indexPath.row]
        let resources = PHAssetResource.assetResources(for: asset)

        var sizeOnDisk: Int64? = 0

        if let resource = resources.first {
            let unsignedInt64 = resource.value(forKey: "fileSize") as? CLong
            sizeOnDisk = Int64(bitPattern: UInt64(unsignedInt64!))
        }

        LogManager.logInfo("SIZE OF IMAGE: \(converByteToHumanReadable(sizeOnDisk!))")

        let imageSizeString = sizeOnDisk!/1048576
        LogManager.logInfo(" SIZE OF IMAGE (1048576): \(imageSizeString)")

        if imageSizeString > 2 {

            targetSize = CGSize.init(width: 1000.0, height: 1000.0)

        } else {
            targetSize = PHImageManagerMaximumSize
        }

        let manager = PHImageManager.default()

        let options: PHImageRequestOptions = PHImageRequestOptions()
        //options.resizeMode = .exact
        options.deliveryMode = .highQualityFormat //.opportunistic
        //options.resizeMode = .exact

        manager.requestImage(for: asset,
                             targetSize: targetSize, //CGSize(width: 375.0, height: 667.0)  ,
                             contentMode: .aspectFit,
                             options: options) { (result, info) in

                                if (info![PHImageResultIsInCloudKey] != nil) {
                                    print("\n\nIS IN CLOUD: \(info![PHImageResultIsInCloudKey] as! Bool)")
                                }

                                guard info![PHImageResultIsDegradedKey] as! Bool == false else {
                                    LogManager.logInfo("Image is degraded")
                                    return
                                }
                                if let image = result {
                                    print("\n\n*********************************==========Local Image*********************************==========\n\n")
                                    let imageData: NSData = NSData(data: UIImageJPEGRepresentation((image), 1)!)

                                    let frameImageData: NSData = NSData(data: UIImageJPEGRepresentation((image), 0.1)!)
                                    let frameImageCompressed: UIImage = UIImage(data: frameImageData as Data)!

                                    LogManager.logInfo(" SIZE OF IMAGE LOADED EARLIER : \(image.size); \(imageData.length/1048576).\(imageData.length%1048576)")
                                    LogManager.logInfo("SIZE OF IMAGE LOADED NOW : \(frameImageCompressed.size); \(frameImageData.length/1048576).\(frameImageData.length%1048576)")

                                    self.displayImage = image
                                    self.delegate.displayTappedImage(displayImage: self.displayImage)
                                } else {

//                                    if (self.getImage(asset: asset)) != nil {
//                                        self.displayImage = self.getImage(asset: asset) //image
//                                        self.delegate.displayTappedImage(displayImage: self.displayImage)

//UNCOMMENT LATER
                                    print("\n\n*********************************==========Cloud Image*********************************==========\n\n")
                                    let options = PHImageRequestOptions()
                                    options.deliveryMode = .highQualityFormat
                                    options.isSynchronous = true
                                    //options.isNetworkAccessAllowed = true
                                    options.progressHandler = { (progress, error, stop, info) in
                                        print("PROGRESS: \(progress)") //.debug("\(progress)")
                                    }
                                    options.version = PHImageRequestOptionsVersion.original

                                    PHImageManager.default().requestImage(for: asset, targetSize:  UIScreen.main.bounds.size , contentMode: .aspectFill, options: options) { (image, info) in
                                        if image !=  nil {

                                            //print(info!["PHImageResultIsInCloudKey"] as! Bool)
                                            //compressedImageData = self.compressImage(image: image!)
                                            self.displayImage = image
                                            self.delegate.displayTappedImage(displayImage: self.displayImage)
                                        } else{
                                            // request image with size 200x200
                                            print("MUST NOT EXECUTE")
                                            print("\n\n*********************************==========Local THUMBNAIL  Image*********************************==========\n\n")
                                            let options: PHImageRequestOptions = PHImageRequestOptions()
                                            //options.resizeMode = .exact
                                            options.deliveryMode = .highQualityFormat //.opportunistic
                                            //options.resizeMode = .exact

                                            PHImageManager.default().requestImage(for: asset, targetSize: CGSize.init(width: 150, height: 150), contentMode: .aspectFill, options: options) { (image, info) in
                                                if image !=  nil {

                                                    self.displayImage = image
                                                    self.delegate.displayTappedImage(displayImage: self.displayImage)
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
//UNCOMMENT LATER
//                                    }
//                                    else {

                                    // show popup saying download the image from icloud in this device as it's just a thumbnail
//                                    self.createAlert(title: "Photo Not Accessible", message: "Please download it from iCloud to use it.")

//                                    }

                                }
        }
        collectionView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    }
}

extension CameraRollViewController {

    func createAlert(title: String, message: String) {

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: { (action) in
            alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            LogManager.logInfo("OK Pressed")
            self.collectionView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        }))
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func converByteToHumanReadable(_ bytes:Int64) -> String {

        let formatter:ByteCountFormatter = ByteCountFormatter()
        formatter.countStyle = .binary
        return formatter.string(fromByteCount: Int64(bytes))
    }






    func getImage(asset: PHAsset) -> UIImage?  {

        var assetImage: UIImage?
        let options = PHImageRequestOptions()
        options.isSynchronous = true
        options.isNetworkAccessAllowed = true

        PHImageManager.default().requestImage(for: asset, targetSize: UIScreen.main.bounds.size, contentMode: .aspectFill, options: options) { (image, info) in
            assetImage = image
        }

        return assetImage
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try below code.

```
__block NSString* tempPath;
// Add it to the photo library
[[PHPhotoLibrary sharedPhotoLibrary] performChanges:^{
    PHAssetChangeRequest *assetChangeRequest = [PHAssetChangeRequest creationRequestForAssetFromImage:image];

    if (self.assetCollection) {
        PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest *assetCollectionChangeRequest = [PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest changeRequestForAssetCollection:self.assetCollection];
        [assetCollectionChangeRequest addAssets:@[[assetChangeRequest placeholderForCreatedAsset]]];
    }
    tempPath = [[assetChangeRequest placeholderForCreatedAsset] localIdentifier];
} completionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
    PHFetchResult* assetResult = [PHAsset fetchAssetsWithLocalIdentifiers:@[tempPath] options:nil];
    if (!success) {
        NSLog(@"Error creating asset: %@", error);
    } else {
        PHFetchResult* assetResult = [PHAsset fetchAssetsWithLocalIdentifiers:@[tempPath] options:nil];
        PHAsset *asset = [assetResult firstObject];
        [[PHImageManager defaultManager] requestImageDataForAsset:asset options:nil resultHandler:^(NSData *imageData, NSString *dataUTI, UIImageOrientation orientation, NSDictionary *info) {
            UIImage* newImage = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
            self.imgView.image = newImage;
        }];
    }
}];
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use the Following Code.

```
`#pragma mark - Create Custom Album name

-(void)saveImageWithAlbumNameAndImage:(UIImage *)image
{
__block PHFetchResult *photosAsset;
__block PHAssetCollection *collection;
__block PHObjectPlaceholder *placeholder;

// Find the album
PHFetchOptions *fetchOptions = [[PHFetchOptions alloc] init];
fetchOptions.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"title = %@", MKCustomPhotoAlbumName];
collection = [PHAssetCollection fetchAssetCollectionsWithType:PHAssetCollectionTypeAlbum
                                                      subtype:PHAssetCollectionSubtypeAny
                                                      options:fetchOptions].firstObject;
// Create the album
if (!collection)
{
    [[PHPhotoLibrary sharedPhotoLibrary] performChanges:^{
        PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest *createAlbum = [PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest creationRequestForAssetCollectionWithTitle:MKCustomPhotoAlbumName];

        placeholder = [createAlbum placeholderForCreatedAssetCollection];
    } completionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
        if (success)
        {
            PHFetchResult *collectionFetchResult = [PHAssetCollection fetchAssetCollectionsWithLocalIdentifiers:@[placeholder.localIdentifier]
                                                                                                        options:nil];
            collection = collectionFetchResult.firstObject;
        }
    }];
}

// Save to the album
[[PHPhotoLibrary sharedPhotoLibrary] performChanges:^{
    PHAssetChangeRequest *assetRequest = [PHAssetChangeRequest creationRequestForAssetFromImage:image];
    placeholder = [assetRequest placeholderForCreatedAsset];
    photosAsset = [PHAsset fetchAssetsInAssetCollection:collection options:nil];
    PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest *albumChangeRequest = [PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest changeRequestForAssetCollection:collection
                                                                                                                  assets:photosAsset];
    [albumChangeRequest addAssets:@[placeholder]];
} completionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
    if (success)
    {
        NSString *UUID = [placeholder.localIdentifier substringToIndex:36];
        NSLog(@"UUID : %@",UUID);
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"%@", error);
    }
}];
}`
```

Here MKCustomPhotoAlbumName is the Macro and Placed the Name of the Album you wanted to create

As you can observe from the code that Your Image is saved into customary created Album in the photos app iPhone. and if it is Already created then saved directly into it